# Removing borders from a button element

Tags: html, css, styled-components

I have this button:

[image]

With the following styling :

```
const SubmitButton = styled.button`
    width: 275px; 
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
`;
```

I removed the main border, but now I keep this left white spacing if you look closely.

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the orange coming from? When I made a button with those styles, all that came out was a borderless button with a red background. Maybe could we see the code a little more clearly? I don't really remember 'styled' being something in javascript.

This is my button and my code and see if it helps you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Blog</title>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button style='width:275px;height: 30px;background-color: red;border:none;outline:none;'>Login</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the output:
[The Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9j8c.png)

Comment: FYI, `styled` means StyledComponents are being used

Comment: Oh sorry, I kind of a beginner but still I wonder why that's happening. Maybe it's a bug. I really don't know. Honestly, you should just stick with the normal version for like ```login_btn = document.createElement('button')```,```login_btn.innerText = 'Login'```, use login_btn.style for the styles (or you could make a function to automatically do that for you, then get the body element (```body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')```), and finally, do ```body.appendChild(login_btn)```. You could do all if that if you really wanted to use Javascript (which I wouldn't).

Comment: didn't work :( , i dont think this can be fixed. Maybe i'll just use input type submit instead

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about why the button is not aligned to the left, it depends on the styles applied to the button container (which could be the page itself).

Some things you can try:

- Adding `text-align:left` to the container style
- Adding `self-align: left` to the button style
- Removing padding or setting `padding-left: 0` from the container